# To getting values on basket

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

```
session_start();
if(isset($_REQUEST['action']) && $_REQUEST['action']!="")
if ($action == "addToBasket")
{
    $rmrradio1 = 3;
    $rmrradio2 = 5.5;
    $rmrradio2 = 16;
}
```

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("input[type='radio']").click(function() { 
        var price = $(this).attr("value");
        var name =  $(this).attr("name");
        add_payment_value(price,name); 
    });  
});

function add_payment_value(price) { 
    // here you can use $.ajax function to add your 'price value' to your cart 
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        url: "make-payment.php"// file where you can add price to your database 
        data: "rmr"=+price+" &action=addtobasket ", 
        success: function(){} // return something on success 
    }); 
}
```

I have written the code like this. This is for a shopping cart site. The above value just added with basket (add my cart) when click the radio button and also i want to know about the jquery  I don't know either this code is correct or not. But i need some one help to implement my project. Can any one give me a right code. Sorry if my q sounds unclear.

Comment: A "right code" to do **what?** I'm sorry, but I can't work out what your question is; could you edit your question to state what the *problem* is, and what you need *help* with?

Comment: that code is not work with me

Comment: How? What are you expecting, what are you getting instead? Any error messages, any unexpected behaviour, anything that could help us understand what the actual _problem_ is? To us, this is just a fragment of code that has no meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
  $("input[type='radio']").click(function()
 {        
  var price = this.value;     
    var name = this.name;      
   add_payment_value(price,name);    
  });  
 }); 

function add_payment_value(price,name) {  
$.post("make-payment.php", { name: name, price: price } 
,

 function(data){

     alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
   });

}
```

You get the vars in the `make-payment.php` like this:

```
$_POST['price'];

$_POST['name'];
```